# log4j DailyRollingFileAppender not adding footer

Tags: java, json, logging, log4j, slf4j

My goal is to use `log4j` to roll (json-formatted) messages into a log file and make the resulting log file a json-valid structure as a result. What I currently have in `log4j.properties` is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.File=out.log
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=com.foobar.CustomLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m,%n
```

Where `CustomLayout` looks like:

```
class CustomLayout extends PatternLayout {

    @Override
    String getHeader() {
        return "[\n"
    }

    @Override
    String getFooter() {
        return "{}\n]"
    }
}
```

However, at the end of my execution, all my files are *not* json-valid because they are left **without a closing bracket**, ie:

```
[
{},
{},
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue and make every rolled file include header **and** footer that I have defined in `CustomLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Log4J adds the footer to the logs when close() is called on the Appender as described here (https://books.google.ch/books?id=vHvY008Zq-YC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=log4j+add+footer&source=bl&ots=yj900eYY7F&sig=WcuhzutCtZ5ZBlV6SpB084sVkkI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRvtD5xrjNAhUIShQKHfxnDJ44ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=log4j%20add%20footer&f=false). You might need to close the appender manually for the footer to be added